# Django: how do I redistribute a project/app that contains extendable HTML templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, pip

I am reading through the Django tutorial [How to write reusable apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/). I am trying to figure out how to package HTML base templates so that people who install my app (through pip) can extend them (e.g. with `{% extends %}`.) When I import a python module I don't have to know its location on the filesystem, but is that the case for Django templates?

*(Side note: My project consists of plumbing that make it easier to write a specific type of app. So I have various abstract base classes [models, views, forms], template tags, URL configuration, and HTML templates that users can inherit from. It also contains customizations to Django Admin. Right now it is a project but I am trying to package it as an app because according to what I am reading, that seems to be the right way to package Django code, but maybe I should be doing it differently.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a template dir structure like this:

```
awesome_app_name/
    templates/
        awesome_app_name/
            base.html
            cool_template.html
```

This allows someone to extend your templates with:

```
{% extends 'awesome_app_name/cool_template.html' %}
```

OR they could just swap it out with their own template like this:

```
my_app_name/
    templates/
        my_app_name/
            my_template.html
        awesome_app_name/
            cool_template.html  <-- this overloads your template with their own
```

This makes for very flexible templates in shared packages.

**EDIT:**

This works if you configure django with both a template directory for your project and the [app_directories.Loader template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types). I believe this to be the configuration used by most:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

Template loading is then done in the following order:

1. Resolve template from project directory
2. Resolve template from app directories

Here's an example project that follows this structure: https://github.com/brutasse/django-password-reset

Comment: But 'awesome_app_name/cool_template.html' references a template in the current project's template directory, right? Whereas if the package is installed via pip, it would be somewhere in site-packages. The project you linked to says that users must "Create a password_reset/base.html template", whereas I want users to inherit from my base.html.

Comment: Both. I updated the answer to include information about template loading order. The 'awesome_app_name' template namespace will live in your package installed under site-packages. But developers consuming your package can include that same namespace in their project template directory which will "overload" it. Because the 'awesome_app_name' namespace exists in your package it can be used in calls to {% extend %} (no overloading required).